# Imagemagick chop 30px off each edge (variable width and height)

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

I need to chop 30px off each side (top bottom left right). I've tried `crop` and also `-chop 30x30` but that only seems to work on one side;

```
convert -verbose -density 150 -trim pdfs/test/test.pdf -quality 80  -chop 30x30 images/agents/test/temp/test.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an even amount on both sides of a dimension, then the command you want is [`-shave`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#shave)

```
convert -verbose -density 150 -trim pdfs/test/test.pdf -quality 80 -shave 30x30 images/agents/test/temp/test.jpg
```