# ImageMagick: Possible to remove middle in picture?

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick, gimp, inkscape

**Question**

As an example, is there an easy way to crop away the o's in the Google logo (knowing their coordinates in advance)?

The result should then be "Ggle" with a smaller image width than the original because the o's are missing.

It doesn't have to be done with ImageMagick. It could also be Gimp, Inkscape or anyother Linux program, that can be scripted from commandline.

[image]

Comment: You mean, under the assumption that the coordinates are known?

Comment: Yes, I would find the coordinates by trail and error.

Comment: wow, that google image is so big :D looks like a google advertisement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the 'chop' option with 'convert' from the command line - [details](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#chop).

Another option is to use [shave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12200809/2327328).

Note that in both cases you will probably have to make 2 images, left and right piece, and then merge them together with something like the 'append' option ([details](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#append)).

For actual command line scripts, look [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_quad).

Answer (score 7):

If Google.png is 538 x 190 px, then the 'G' is 140px wide and the 'gle' is 208px wide, leaving a block that is 190 x 190 px in the middle that you want to chop out. In ImageMagick:

```
convert Google.png -chop 190x190+141+190 Ggle.png
```

where the first measurement is the size of the block to be chopped and the rest indicates where to start chopping. Resulting in Ggle.png: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
display Google.png
```

Click on the image. A menu will appear. Click ***Transform > Chop***. You can now choose ***Direction*** (Horizontal or Vertical). Now click and drag the portion you want to remove. Now Click ***File > Save***.